# Behaviour of parse-pathname (at least on sbcl)

Tags: path, common-lisp

I know that the rename-file standard function has a somewhat vague specification:

> rename-file modifies the file system in such a way that the file indicated by filespec is renamed to defaulted-new-name.

I also know that there is a long standing issue in sbcl (it uses POSIX rename so it has the same limitations, especially crossing filesystems boundaries).

However there is a behaviour I find quite problematic: let's have a file called `testfile.tmp`, and I want to rename it to `testfile` (without extension, i.e. with empty `pathname-type`). Here I use the sbcl read syntax (but even with `parse-namestring` the result is the same):

```
(rename-file #p"testfile.tmp" #p"newfile")
=>
#P"/home/mrclnz/newfile.tmp"
#P"/home/mrclnz/testfile.tmp"
#P"/home/mrclnz/newfile.tmp"
```

…I've checked in the `rename-file` implementation and it does a `merge-pathnames`. The issue is that `parse-namestring` gives nil type and it get merged with the source. This of course is not good.

Using `uiop:ensure-pathname` I get an :unspecific type so the merge and the renames work fine. On the other hand the printed representation for both is the same, as in:

```
(parse-namestring "newfile") => #P"newfile"
(uiop:ensure-pathname "newfile") => #P"newfile"
```

but, looking inside I have:

```
(pathname-type (parse-namestring "newfile")) => NIL
(pathname-type (uiop:ensure-pathname "newfile")) => :UNSPECIFIC
```

(good luck with print/read roundtrips… maybe they should have made that unreadable?)

So, at the end, what's happening? is all of this legal (as in, unspecified in `parse-namestring`; `rename-file` seems innocent to me, everything using `merge-pathnames` is affected)? should I simply avoid `parse-namestring` as broken? probably the sbcl people didn't think about pathnames without a type (I checked it, even `sb-ext:native-pathname` uses nil as type).

What's the idiomatic way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What coredump wrote is correct, but to answer your specific questions:

- yes, this is conforming behaviour: `rename-file` is documented to merge the second pathname using the first as the default, so it is doing the right thing here;
- SBCL's `parse-namestring` is fine: `parse-namestring`'s job is just to return some kind of pathname, and it's doing that;
- (and `#P` is not SBCL-specific by the way, it's just [a way of calling `parse-namestring` at read-time](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhn.htm)).

As coredump says, `nil` and `:unspecific` are printed identically when printing pathnames: the difference between them is precisely that `nil` means 'this field is not filled but could be' and `:unspecific` means 'this is not present and should not be filled', see [here](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/19_bc.htm).

And in fact the behaviour SBCL (and, at least, LispWorks and Clozure) has, where `(pathname-type (parse-namestring "x"))` is `nil` is generally what you want, because fairly often you want to merge pathnames like this to add extensions to them.  Certainly I do that quite a lot!  I can't see that it's not *allowed* to return `:unspecific`, but I would rather it did not.

So the underlying problem here is that the CL pathname system is just somewhat deficient, and designed with support for filesystems which no longer really exist in mind.  In particular designed with filesystems where file types were a real thing rather than a naming convention and where all files had a type.

The problem then is that you either need to assume (slightly nonportably, but only very slightly so) that `:unspecific` as a pathname type (or other component where it may be allowed), or somehow persuade the system to hand you a name with a type of `:unspecific` if it's willing to which you can then use (if it won't hand you such a name then presumably you're working on a filesystem where types are mandatory anyway!).

I can't think of a way of portably doing the second thing.  Probably in practice the right approach is then to use some portability layer like UIOP to solve the problem, but some kind of minimalist answer would be a function like:

```
(defun ensure-unmergable-type (p)
  (merge-pathnames (pathname p)
                   (load-time-value
                    (make-pathname :type ':unspecific))))
```

Again, this is slightly non-portable and could in theory signal an error at load time, but in practice it will probably work on anything you're likely to use.

Comment: The UIOP parse function in fact returns unspecified and this solved all my problems. Probably was the CL committee that expected every file had a type (a the time)

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio: I don't think they did (or not all of them did): it was, I am sure, like other things, something that everyone knew was not right/finished but the assumption was that implementations would extend things (generally true), there would be another chance to get it right reasonably soon (false) and everyone was just exhausted (true).

Answer (score 2):

> probably the sbcl people didn't think about pathnames without a type

The SBCL people do follow the specification closely, and the specification itself has its own shortcomings with pathnames; they are specified to be able to address files in a variety of file systems that no longer exist, and   do not support everything a contemporary file system does.

In particular,
[19.2.2.2.3 :UNSPECIFIC as a Component Value](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/19_bbbc.htm) indicates that `:unspecific` is not portable, and that means that you rely on what a specific implementation of Common Lisp does on a given file system. That's however how most languages work, I mean when you access files from Python you are also not necessarily portable across filesystems or OSes.

> (good luck with print/read roundtrips… maybe they should have made that unreadable?)

Likewise, the conversion of `:unspecific` as a namestring is covered by section [19.2.2.2.3.1](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/19_bbbca.htm):

> If a pathname is converted to a namestring, the symbols `nil` and `:unspecific` cause the field to be treated as if it were empty. That is, both `nil` and `:unspecific` cause the component not to appear in the namestring.

Comment: Well, I think it would be quite impossible to do file name handling portable (had to work with IBM MVS in the past and their dataset catalog is… peculiar. Also they really have file types!).

Answer (score 1):

I would use `make-pathname` to create a pathname.

For example:

```
(make-pathname :defaults #p"foo" :type :unspecific)
```

Comment: The question was about handling user supplied pathnames. make-pathname and merge-pathnames do… everything else

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio : as in my example you can pass a user supplied pathname as default to make-pathname and fill in the things to change.